# How to send a transaction in private tangle Hornet of IOTA?

Tags: transaction, tangle, hornet, hornet-dashboard

I have deployed an IOTA tangle network on Hornet and it is running successfully on http://localhost:8081/. How do I send a transaction to it?

Are there any steps or could you please share any documents/tutorials to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given swagger docs can be used to connect to Hornet running on localhost.

https://editor.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rufsam/protocol-rfcs/master/text/0026-rest-api/rest-api.yaml